# Авто ssl для новых доменов

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache2, letsencrypt

Есть сервер, подключаю к нему некоторые домены, вопрос - как сделать автоматическую настройку ssl (к примеру, с помощью let's encrypt) без моего участия? К примеру, как это сделано в cloudflare.

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx - официальная мана от сертбота (обратите внимание, там 2 способа, один используется клодфларой!). А вот статья, если будет использоваться докер, она мне помогла: https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71 - делается через докер.

Comment: *lets encrypt* — это сервис для получения и обновления сертификатов. к «настройке ssl» он не имеет вообще никакого отношения. внесите, пожалуйста, уточняющие правки в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]